# Angular 5: Using abstract function in *ngIf

Tags: angular, function, typescript, abstract

how I can use a abstract function in *ngIf ?

```
export abstract class Item
{
    constructor(name: string, url: string, image: string)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.url = url;
        this.image = image;
    }

    private name?: string;
    private url?: string;
    private image?: string;

    public abstract isText(): boolean;
    public abstract isLink(): boolean;
    public abstract isImage(): boolean;

    public get Name(): string 
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    public get Url(): string 
    {
        return this.url;
    }

    public get Image(): string 
    {
        return this.image;
    }
}

export class Image extends Item 
{
    constructor(url:string, image: string)
    {
        super(undefined, url, image);
    }

    public isText(): boolean 
    {
        return false;
    }

    public isLink(): boolean 
    {
        return false;
    }

    public isImage(): boolean 
    {
        return true;
    }
}

export class Link extends Item
{
    constructor(name:string, url: string)
    {
        super(name, url, undefined);
    }

    public isText(): boolean 
    {
        return false;
    }

    public isLink(): boolean 
    {
        return true;
    }

    public isImage(): boolean 
    {
        return false;
    }
}

export class Text extends Item
{
    constructor(name:string)
    {
        super(name, undefined, undefined);
    }

    public isText(): boolean 
    {
        return true;
    }

    public isLink(): boolean 
    {
        return false;
    }

    public isImage(): boolean 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And I want to use the abstract functions like:

```
<div *ngFor="let Item of Category.Items">
    <a *ngIf="Item.isLink" class="animation" (click)="close()">{{Item.Name}}</a>
</div>
```

The problem is that I get this if I print Item.isLink:

**function () { return true; }**

It's like the *nfIf don't execute the function, how I can execute that function to return the value?

Comment: Call the function *ngIf="Item.isLink()"

Comment: `Item.isLink()`

Answer (score 5):

Your `isLink` is a function, so you need to call it via `()` after the property name - `Item.isLink()`

```
<div *ngFor="let Item of Category.Items">
    <a *ngIf="Item.isLink()" class="animation" (click)="close()">{{ Item.Name }}</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Ooh i am so stiooopid, I forgot to add get in prototype :(. Thanks anyway.